# How can I remove the first element of XML using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to remove the first element.
I have the XmlDocument doc which has this xml. Just need to know how to remove the first element "?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?".

This needs to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I need to encode this in base64 after i remove that line and send as a request.

Comment: That's not an element, that's the Processing Instruction. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `XmlDocument` object containing the XML, then you can get the XML without the XML declaration like this:

```
string xml = doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `XmlDeclaration` completely:

```
if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
    doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
string xml = doc.OuterXml;
```

Comment: this works thank you.